# System.Security.SecurityException With WebClient GET Request

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm writing a Silverlight application that needs to interface with a server via GET/POST requests. My code looks like the following:

```
Uri serviceUri = new Uri(my_URI);
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OnRequestComplete);
client.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
```

However, when the callback function is called, I am getting a System.Security.SecurityException. I've read multiple questions on here from people with similar errors, however all of their issues seem to stem from cross domain issues while debugging. When I run my code, it runs with `http://localhost:...` as the domain, so that shouldn't be the issue I don't think. Here's the full error if that helps at all:

```
{System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}
```

Thanks for any help. This has been a very frustrating issue.

UPDATE:

I screwed around with it a lot and eventually got everything to work. Not 100% what did it though... I ended up copy/pasting the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files everywhere imaginable, created a new Silverlight project and copied everything there, along with a few other things. If anyone else runs into this problem, that's about as much advice as I have to give :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766574/using-web-client-in-silverlight

Comment: He's running from a file:// URI. Like I stated above, I'm running from localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is still violates same-origin policy because the port numbers don't match: i.e. the XAP uri's port and the my_URI port do not match. And hence the `System.Security.SecurityException`. Could you try hosting the my_URI relative to your XAP.

Or even better, can you try interacting with the server using WCF.

Comment: Interesting. I wrote a quick little C# app to test out sending and receiving requests and that seemed to work. Assuming this still is a same-origin issue, how would I go about solving it? I've already tried all (reasonable) suggestions I found online such as adding the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml